# How to compare files from Solaris and Linux

Tags: linux, solaris

I want to compare the contents of same file present there in both Solaris and Linux for our testing purpose.
I there is any tool available for that.
If I want to develop new tool, haw can I achieve that?

We are migrating project from Solaris to Linux.
We want to verify the final output with is there in binary format by comparing them.
Both the files are there in different systems.
Please suggest me how we will do that comparison.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more background to get useful responses. Are the solaris and linux systems different physical systems, or is it some kind of dual boot scenario? Perhaps you have ssh access from one system to the other? Do the files contain text data, or general binary data?

Comment: Is your solaris running on sparc or Intel platform? Is your plan to compile source code from solaris to Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Unix and Linux have a number of built-in file comparison tools.  Whatever tool you use will need access to both the file which is on Solaris and the one on Linux - how you achieve that is a different matter but you can copy the files to one system or share them via network shares.

Assuming the files to be compared are seen as
`/linux/filename.txt`
and
`/solaris/filename.txt`

You may compare them using the command
`diff /linux/filename.txt /solaris/filename.txt`

For binary files, or very large files that you don't want to transfer over the network, you can use checksums to determine whether files are identical.  md5 checksums can be generated on the system where the file is  and and then the result can be copied to compare.  For example to get an md5 checksum on Solaris you can use
`digest -a md5 filename`

On Linux the same can be achieved using

`md5sum filename`

The result can be copy-pasted or transferred via the network to one system.

If you put each md5 checksum on a new line in the file to see whether they are all identical use the sort unique command.  It will print each "md5 sum" that is unique, so if the files are supposed to be identical then you can expect only one line of output from a command such as
`sort -u md5sum_results.txt`

Update:
Since you are moving your work from Solaris to Linux I would suggest the following general approach.

1. Create a backup on the Solaris side.  There are too many ways to even start thinking about all of them but cpio is my go-to for many reasons, particularly because it deals well with strange file types:
   `find /source/directory | cpio -oV > /backup/data.cpio`
2. Check the checksum of this file:
   `digest -a md5 /backup/data.cpio`
3. Copy the file via the network, maybe use:
   `scp /backup/data.cpio user@linuxhost:/incoming`

Other options include NFS-mounts and rsync and many other ways.

4. On the Linux side check the file is un-modified:
   `md5sum /incoming/data.cpio`
5. If the MD5 checksum match, extract the backup:
   `cd /target/directory; cpio -iV < /incoming/data.cpio`

Note: scp is unlikely to "corrupt" your file.  If you did skip the check of the checksum, cpio will usually (always, but not absolutely 100% guaranteed) catch the corruption).  md5 checksums will increase your confidence in the file but it is rarely needed to go to this level.